# Object's position & rotation is not getting saved / loaded (Unity Engine)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, save, position, load

I need to save the player's position and rotation in-game. I use Binary Formatter and 2 buttons: 'Save' and 'Load' for this purpose. The script saves public Vector3 data if I write it down manually, save it, and then load the scene again. However, the player (just a cube) does not change its position and rotation. To fix this, I added:

```
void FixedUpdate()
    {
        position = player.transform.position;
        rotation = player.transform.rotation;
    }
```

But that did not help. I use 2 scripts in order to make this work:

**Player.cs**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject player;
    public Vector3 position;
    public Quaternion rotation;

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        position = player.transform.position;
        rotation = player.transform.rotation;
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        SaveLoadManager.SavePlayer(this);
    }

    public void Load()
    {
        float[] loadedStats = SaveLoadManager.LoadPlayer();

        Vector3 loadedPos = new Vector3(loadedStats[0], loadedStats[1], loadedStats[2]);
        Vector3 loadedRot = new Vector3(loadedStats[3], loadedStats[4], loadedStats[5]);

        player.transform.position = loadedPos;
        player.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(loadedRot);
    }
}
```

**SaveLoadManager.cs**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.IO;

public static class SaveLoadManager
{
    public static void SavePlayer(Player player)
    {
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        FileStream stream = new FileStream(Application.persistentDataPath + "/player.save", FileMode.Create);

        PlayerData data = new PlayerData(player);

        bf.Serialize(stream, data);
        stream.Close();
    }

    public static float[] LoadPlayer()
    {
        if (File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + "/player.save"))
        {
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            FileStream stream = new FileStream(Application.persistentDataPath + "/player.save", FileMode.Open);

            PlayerData data = bf.Deserialize(stream) as PlayerData;

            stream.Close();
            return data.stats;
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("File does not exist.");
            return new float[6];
        }
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class PlayerData
{
    public float[] stats;

    public PlayerData(Player player)
    {
        stats = new float[6];

        stats[0] = player.position.x;
        stats[1] = player.position.y;
        stats[2] = player.position.z;

        stats[3] = player.rotation.x;
        stats[4] = player.rotation.y;
        stats[5] = player.rotation.z;
    }
}
```

I'm quite new to Save-Load systems and Binary Formatting, so I hope you'll give me a hand.

Thanks in advance!

[image: A GIF demonstrating the problem.]

If someone else encounters a similar problem: besides adding the code in the Answer below, I also changed player.transform.rotation.(x/y/z); to player.transform.eulerAngles.(x/y/z); in SaveLoadManager.cs to make rotation work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I'm missing something, but I don't see anywhere in your Load() method that actually sets the Player's position to the loaded values.  Instead it looks like you're passing the loaded values into unnecessary variables, then overwriting those constantly in FixedUpdate().

Maybe try something like:

```
   public void Load()
    {
        float[] loadedStats = SaveLoadManager.LoadPlayer();
        
        Vector3 loadedPos = new Vector3(loadedStats[0], loadedStats[1], loadedStats[2]);
        Vector3 loadedRot = new Vector3(loadedStats[3], loadedStats[4], loadedStats[5]);
        player.transform.position = loadedPos ;
        player.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(loadedRot);

    }
```

And you can just get rid of the position and rotation variables on the Player script.

Comment: Your code perfectly worked out for the player's position. However, the player's rotation is set to 0, 0, 0, every time I load.

Comment: Hmmm...I don't immediately see anything that would cause this.  Are you certain that the rotation is being saved correctly?  If you print out the values when saving, do you find the values you'd expect?

Comment: I'm really just wondering if the GameObject your player script is attached to is rotating at all?  There are other ways you might be doing rotation without changing the player.transform.rotation value directly.

Comment: Yep, when I remove FixedUpdate() and manually set rotation values it works fine.

Comment: You don't need to be doing anything in FixedUpdate(), since that was only overwriting your unnecessary values.  Can you edit your post to show the current version of the code you're using for the Player script?  I think your saving works fine.

Comment: Of course, I edited it. It doesn't work without FixedUpdate() because I need to check the player's movement (position and rotation) every frame.

Comment: Ok.  You are declaring two public variables on your Player script, right near the top, called "position" and "rotation".  I'm guessing other scripts in your project use these variables to do stuff?

Comment: They will do stuff. Right now I don't have any other scripts and set the values manually in the scene view just in order to test. The biggest mystery for me is not working rotation. I embedded a GIF in the post.

Comment: Ok.  Regardless, those two variables are redundant.  Every GameObject has a Transform component attached with a .transform reference set up, and every Transform has the position and rotation values publicly exposed.  You can access your player's position/rotation by calling player.transform.position and player.transform.rotation (using the public "player" reference you declare).  I'm not sure exactly what's going wrong, but it's happening because you have two copies of the position/rotation data.  One on the player's transform, and a redundant copy in your "position/rotation" variables.

Comment: So start by deleting the two publicly declared "position" and "rotation" variables, and only accessing your players position and rotation with player.transform.position, and player.transform.rotation.  And then you can delete the FixedUpdate() call entirely -- transform data is updated automatically in fixed update.  You were just updating the redundant variables.

Comment: Glad I could help.  Good luck with your project!